# Can't add or upgrade iAd.framework

Tags: iphone, xcode4, frameworks, iad, adwhirl

I have upgraded AdWhirl for an Iphone app. Everything is fine so far, except the AdWhirl adapter had problems with iAd. I reasoned that it was because I linked an iAd framework that was too old. I had not upgraded iAd.framework in the app since XCode 3.x.

I removed the iAd.framework from Build Phases/Link Libraries with Binary, in the hope that I would be able to link the new framework from XCode 4.

But it's not in the list, and if I select Other... the framework is not found on the harddisk. I opened the XCode .mpkg to see if it was there, but it wasn't.

I've found similar questions, but they either apply to some other framework, or recommend to make it optional. Surely that would not guaranteedly put iAd ads in my app, and at any rate I can't make it optional since I can't add it to the list in the first place.

Just as I upgraded the other ad frameworks, I should like to upgrade the iAd framework. Where do I get the iAd framework?

Comment: What version of XCode are you using? I think that when you update version of XCode, the packages also get automatically updated.

Comment: You need to upgrade to XCode 4.5 now I think

Comment: Sure, could you check if you can add iAd.framework in your XCode 4.5 and make it optional? So I know it solves the problem and the problem isn't elsewhere.

Comment: Yup, I've integrated iAd.framework in a number of projects and made it optional to target down to 4.3